# Dev Hub in Partner org

Tags: salesforcedx, dev-hub

I have a partner Org where Environment hub is setup. I couldnt see the Dev hub option in the org.

I know that it is available in: Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience
Dev Hub available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions
Scratch orgs available in: Developer, Enterprise, Group, and Professional Editions

I also couldnt see the Devhub option in my other Production org which happens to be Enterprise Edition.

Please help in getting the Devhub enabled in either of the org.

Comment: You dont see it when you go to Setup and then type in Dev Hub? Make sure that the your org is not a Developer org

Comment: @Arun SFDC, Any findings around the same? I was also looking forward to such a scenario.